# How to convert DateTime to UnixTime Stamp ?in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

Hi the response from Facebook i am getting the date is fallowing format
"Mon Feb 21 23:15:58 IST 2015"
but i need to get the response of today face book page feeds  only.
in order to achieve that i need to convert the date object in to timestamps number.
i am cross checking the result in fallowing tool but the output is not coming properly.
http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

please help to get proper o/p?

Comment: Java time is milliseconds, Unix time is in seconds, both share the same epoch (a time of 0 is the same date for Java and Unix). Now, do you want to convert the String to Date or a Date to the prescribed String format?

Comment: Date to String format